# Retrieve table id with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have some tables that are generated with automatic id, so I didn't know the table id before to do some stuff on it.

To retrieve my id, I use this jQuery light code

```
 $('table').each(function(){
                alert(this.id);
            });
```

Idea of the html code generated:

```
<table id="table1">...</table><table id="table2">...</table>
```

This jQuery code give me all table ids.
My tables have some button to add rows, so if I click on the add button for the 2nd table, that only add the row for the 2nd table (the code upside give me all table id on my web page)

How can I retrieve the curent table id? (I have try to play with prev() but I think I don't play as well as I must do)

Note: I didn't need code to append a row, I could do that ;)

Comment: **a)** the button should contain info about the ID of the table for which it works (e.g. `data-tableid='234'`) or **b)** it should be a child or a sibling of the table => in this case please **post your HTML** with both the table and its "add row" button (P.S.: *use `<code>` or `<pre>` tags to post html code*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking for:

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).parents('table').attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> so if i clic on the add button for the 2nd table, that only add the
>   row for the 2nd table

You should do:

```
$('.btnClass').click(function(){
   var table_id = $(this).closest('table')[0].id;
});
```

## Update

Notice that you are also using numeric `id` value for your tables which is invalid, try using alpha or alphanumeric characters for example `table_1`, `table_2`, etc

Comment: i use numeric values to my example, but in real it s alphanumerique (table+id of table --> giving table1 / table2 ...). ty for answering ;)

Comment: @Yeurl: Then you should post that in your question in the first place to avoid confusion and waste others' time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that :

```
$('table').each(function(){
   $(this).parent().find('#buttonId').click(function() {
      // Code to append a row
   });
});
```

Btw, it will be better that you give details about the DOM architecture to the button and the table (`$(x).find(..)` is not the fastest way in performance)..

Comment: DOM is pretty light in this. So, i don t think it s need ;). Adam Merrifield give for me the best solution ... but may be there more pretty (still learning jquery ;) )... by the way, ty for answering